# Get From Address from message_from_string() in Python

Tags: python, email

Can someone please tell me how to get the from address from email.message_from_string() in Python? Thanks! I tried

```
message = email.message_from_string(email_text)
from = message['From']
```

However, that did not seem to work.

Here is the email I am parsing:

```
Received: (qmail 16903 invoked by uid 30297); 27 Jul 2013 15:16:51 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO p3pismtp01-015.prod.phx3.secureserver.net) ([10.6.12.15])
          (envelope-sender <tlovett88@gmail.com>)
          by p3plsmtp10-03.prod.phx3.secureserver.net (qmail-1.03) with SMTP
          for <reply@guestretain.com>; 27 Jul 2013 15:16:51 -0000
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result: AkYDACPh81FKfVKyk2dsb2JhbABbgkQCgUVUvQmBEAgWDgEBAQEHCwsJFAQkghsJAQEEAUABGx4DAQsGBQEBAQECBQM4IgERAQUBHAYTh30BAwkGmxaMT4J/hBcKGScNZId0AQUMj3iEBQOXX49nFimDAYFVIA
Received: from mail-we0-f178.google.com ([74.125.82.178])
  by p3pismtp01-015.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with ESMTP; 27 Jul 2013 08:16:51 -0700
Received: by mail-we0-f178.google.com with SMTP id u57so2691391wes.23
        for <reply@guestretain.com>; Sat, 27 Jul 2013 08:16:50 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:in-reply-to:references:date:message-id:subject:from:to
         :content-type;
        bh=yU9O8/uUeQbclKzg3n9YD5bu4chhx/D44TL6gOzd2ag=;
        b=aFXVUYwpBwvVfAzzTQSbpAIR1rbMq/I32DPy1DFLpgqgbtIrmUCbp/EQJyvqupxXSe
         chZmaH7ALuMurnlTbpjOLqHBZx550U9gmYl/+tk6Ql7HgYOsYW+0eIpeyWGfgAlgyz3O
         ISyiKyjhjLVs6Cw01LJW9n2zgssNqcE8uMqpqnVagl33bbKbI3ODWCvnmjhfwQBVHhjm
         /CMXJ1dUIfcleFHRdH26lWBEm2Z54dYe06EPwJ6zF7LGFRBakF120kY+gUXpnrlfwZi9
         XyFevTI6lvL6+W28b8fxUisGzfL9zmvPb9wHyOpHix5kuvj06Z3FvFhIer03La/Fhd7k
         EWtA==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.180.20.228 with SMTP id q4mr2165577wie.60.1374938210558;
 Sat, 27 Jul 2013 08:16:50 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.216.164.9 with HTTP; Sat, 27 Jul 2013 08:16:50 -0700 (PDT)
In-Reply-To: <15669247.20130725035929.51f0a2a1834095.64964363@mail333.us4.mandrillapp.com>
References: <15669247.20130725035929.51f0a2a1834095.64964363@mail333.us4.mandrillapp.com>
Date: Sat, 27 Jul 2013 11:16:50 -0400
Message-ID: <CAND88j9txyLT7YOqcrSoRYZ9-SDHaCwBsc-ZNR_1+iYPrM0N5w@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Re: New message regarding your stay on 2013-06-19 to 2013-06-29 at
 the The Marriot <SRID2>
From: Taylor Lovett <tlovett88@gmail.com>
To: Taylor Lovett <reply@guestretain.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=f46d04218485a0ea0404e27fbf5b
X-Nonspam: None

--f46d04218485a0ea0404e27fbf5b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

Test email!

--f46d04218485a0ea0404e27fbf5b
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`from` is a reserved keyword. Use a different variable name. Your code otherwise works fine:

```
>>> import email
>>> message = email.message_from_string(email_text)
>>> message['From']
'Taylor Lovett <tlovett88@gmail.com>'
>>> from = message['From']
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from = message['From']
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from_address = message['From']
>>> from_address
'Taylor Lovett <tlovett88@gmail.com>'
```