# python email.message_from_string() parse problems

Tags: python, parsing, email

My setup uses fetchmail to pull emails from Gmail, which are processed by procmail and passes it to a python script.

When I use `email.message_from_string()`, the resulting object is not parsed as an email object.  `get_payload()` returns the header/body/payload text of the email as a single text blob.

This is the text it returns:

```
From example@gmail.com  Sat Aug 17 19:20:44 2013
>From example  Sat Aug 17 19:20:44 2013
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: from ie-in-f109.1e100.net [74.125.142.109]
    by VirtualBox with IMAP (fetchmail-6.3.21)
    for <example@localhost> (single-drop); Sat, 17 Aug 2013 19:20:44 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.70.131.110 with HTTP; Sat, 17 Aug 2013 19:20:42 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Sat, 17 Aug 2013 19:20:42 -0700
Delivered-To: example@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CAAsp4m0GBeVg80-ryFgNvNNAj_QPguzbX3DqvMSx-xSGZM18Pw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test 19:20
From: example <example@gmail.com>
To: example <example@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a1133435474449004e42f7861

--001a1133435474449004e42f7861
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

19:20

--001a1133435474449004e42f7861
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<div dir="ltr">19:20</div>

--001a1133435474449004e42f7861--
```

My code:

```
full_msg = sys.stdin.read()
msg = email.message_from_string(full_msg)
msg['to']          # returns None
msg.get_payload()  # returns the text above
```

What am I missing to get Python to properly interpret the email?

I see from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899413/get-from-address-from-message-from-string-in-python) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050298/parsing-email-with-python) that I may not be getting the proper email headers somewhere along the line, but I cannot confirm. That ">" on line 2 is not a typo: it's in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of ">" being "in the text" as you say, whatever that means - it's wrong. After removing this character:

> `>python test.py <input.txt`
>   `example <example@gmail.com>`
>   `[<email.message.Message instance at 0x02810288>,`
>   `<email.message.Message instance at 0x02810058>]`

So the error is not in parsing the message, but in the ">" character somehow corrupting your email text.

Comment: Don't know what's adding that "<", but once I delete it in the script, the parser works fine. The entire system now works as it should. Thanks for the idea.